# Image corrupted or truncated Phonegap

Tags: javascript, mysql, cordova, camera

I'm using Phonegap to develop an android application. Users take photo, the photo is stored in a mysql database (medium-blob column). I store them using a simple INSERT INTO query, without changing the data. The data are sent server side using a REST call (PUT)

Here's an example of the content of this column:

```
thumb = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDACgcHiMeG...'
```

It is written on the phonegap documentation that the image captured through the camera is encoded in base 64.The problem is, when i try to retrieve my images in the database, I cannot display them using this JS code :

```
$('#myImg').attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + data
```

Any ideas of where this "Image corrupted and truncated" come from ? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was located in the way I was sending the images. 
I was sending the data through a string. I tried to pass them nested in a json object and It worked.